# Callback of deferred to be executed while promise is pending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

How do I configure code to be run while the promise of a `jQuery.Deferred` is being waited for? So like:

```
$.when(someAJAX).whatever(function() {
    // run this while the AJAX is loading
}).done(function() {
    // run this when it is done
});
```

I've checked [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), and have found nothing, but maybe I missed something out (`deferred.progress()` doesn't work here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is much simpler than what you're trying to do.  Instead, you can do this:

```
$.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises).done(function() {
    // code here when ajax call is done
});
// this code will execute right after the ajax call was initiated
// put code here to set state while ajax is loading
```

Comment: Aah, that's smart. Thanks! By the way, the reason I'm using `$.when()` is because I have an array of promises (so I actually have `$.when.apply(promises)...` in my code). I just decided to offer a simplified model here :)

Comment: @Bluefire - OK, then you can use `$.when(array of promises)` in place of the `$.ajax()` I have in my answer.

Comment: `$.when.apply(null, promises)` I hope.